# C preprocessor tokenization does not expand macro?

Tags: c, gcc, macros, c99, c-preprocessor

1) Why is the macro MSG not expanded in the following expression?

```
#define MSG Hello
#define HELLO(name)  MSG ## name

void HELLO(Dave) () {}
```

Using

```
gcc -E -P test.cpp
```

Output:

```
void MSGDave () {}
```

`MSG name` expands to `Hello Dave`. And `MSG # name` expands to `Hello "Dave"`.  So what causes gcc not to expand `MSG ## name`?

2) Is there a workaround?

Is there a preprocessor directive like defined(x), such as expand(x)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#define MSG Hello
#define cat(x, y) x ## y
#define cat2(x, y) cat(x, y)
#define HELLO(name) cat2(MSG,name)
```

[Live demo @ ideone](http://ideone.com/8iJHIW).

Comment: Excellent! This is the 2nd and most important half of the answer - the workaround. @Yu responded first with the reason -- this 'bug' is by design.

Answer (score 5):

Because macro arguments are not substituted when preceded or followed by a `##` operator.

> #### C11 §6.10.3.1 Argument substitution
>
> After the arguments for the invocation of a function-like macro have been identified, argument substitution takes place. A parameter in the replacement list, **unless preceded by a `#` or `##` preprocessing token or followed by a `##` preprocessing token (see below)**, is
> replaced by the corresponding argument after all macros contained therein have been expanded. Before being substituted, each argument’s preprocessing tokens are completely macro replaced as if they formed the rest of the preprocessing file; no other preprocessing tokens are available.

Comment: Nice. You nailed half the question -- why it isn't expanded. Then @n.m. gave the other very important half -- the workaround.